# ERESTARTSYS from get_user_pages and pending fatal signal?

Tags: linux, memory, logging, kernel, sigkill

I'm testing some software+driver for it on linux, and the driver uses the get_user_pages() in its internal functions.
At some point my driver receives ERESTARTSYS error (-512) from the get_user_pages(), and according to the kernel code it happens because "If we have a pending SIGKILL, don't keep faulting pages and potentially allocating memory." - it's a comment from memory.c kernel file.

How can I see who sent this SIGKILL and why? I was trying to look in /var/log/kern.log file but couldn't see anything there about any signal.

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe you can for SIGKILL (others, yes), unless you are willing to patch the kernel to give you the signal information.  In which case, you can inspect the si_code and si_pid values, per the docs: http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009696699/basedefs/signal.h.html

Eg, if your signal info is in siptr:

```
if ((siptr)->si_code <= 0) {
   printk(KERN_DEBUG "kill sent by process %u", (siptr)->si_pid);
}
```

The if check isn't strictly necessary: it restricts the printk() to those signals raised by a kill().  If the kernel raised the signal, si_code would be greater than 0.

Answer (score 1):

I had exactly same problem.
But instead of in get_user_pages() i would get -ERESTARTSYS from sock_sendmsg().

To debug this issue what i did was add a logging message in 
linux-3.2/kernel/signal.c:  __send_signal().

And to avoid message filling up in kernel logs.
I would strncmp(t->comm, "myprogramname") And then log t->comm, t->pid, current->comm and current->pid.

Also i realized it is not only SIGKILL but any other signal pending too,
Then the call will return -ERESTARTSYS.

So the my next step was to find out who is giving my program a signal.
And add handlers for all signals (except SIGKILL, which i cant really handle).
Lucky for me it was not SIGKILL.

Adding handler may not help your case, but logging will identify who is sending and the reason.

Handling may help others who have similar problem.